# how to export mapbox studio style to vector tiles?

Tags: vector-tiles, mapbox-studio, mapbox-vector-tile

1. I created a map style in Mapbox Studio.
2. Using [https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{userid}/{styleid}/tiles/256/{z}/{x}/{y}@2x?access_token={access_token}](https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/%7Buserid%7D/%7Bstyleid%7D/tiles/256/%7Bz%7D/%7Bx%7D/%7By%7D@2x?access_token=%7Baccess_token%7D), I can put the raster tiles on my leaflet-react web project.

But, how can I get vector tiles out of this? Am I stupid? No documentation anywhere seems to point me towards this workflow with mapbox and I am going crazy on a tight deadline. What have I missed? I want to use mapbox because already have the key and need free (until 200,000 requests).